# How do you link two outposts in Starfield?

Tags: starfield

I created two outposts in Starfield on different planets but not sure how to link them together.

Must they be in the same system or can I link different systems too? And will they all link to a single output like storage?

Comment: @Neon1024 no that one is specifically talking about a quest for Uranium, the answer below is more aligned to this general question and mentions the types of cargo links (first and second)

Comment: The answer on that question is the same as the one on this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can be on the same system, but this is not mandatory.

The difference between two outposts on the same system and on different systems is the type of Cargo Link you need.

The first one (same system) needs a 'Cargo Link'.
The second one (different systems) needs an 'Cargo Link Inter-System'.
The main difference is the need of Helium-3 to run the second one.

You can control where they link (deliver) the resources inside the Control Console (on top of the Cargo Link landing platform).

Comment: Can you go a bit more in depth? It would help many others having the same question in the future. I get the general idea of what you said but for example `You can control where they link (deliver) the ressources inside the Control Console (on top of the Cargo Link landing platform).` is not very clear

Comment: If you have built a Cargo Link in your outpost you can walk upstairs to the landing zone. There you will find the Control Console. Open this console and connect your outgoing link. You would have to ask more precisely what you want to know. I suggest to just try it. Many things become more obvious if you use the mentioned Control Console.

Comment: Just beware that the two cargo links built at each outpost transfers cargo between the  two outposts. If you were to add a third outpost and send to the other linked outposts through the existing cargo links, cargo will be shared amongst the three. If you want the third one to only share with one of the other outposts, you'll need to create another separate cargo link at the other outpost and connect with that.